# query in postgresql convert to Django orm

Tags: python, postgresql, django-rest-framework, pgadmin

I want to convert the postgresql code into Django ORM query.

Description:
template = ['Guidelines', 'Widget_Details', 'Mapping_Template', 'Data_Upload']
When i upload the excel file it validates the function and update in the application

Postgres Query:

```
sqltcket = "select ticket_limit from "+dbNameQry+".dboard_computed_system_user_setting"
    print('asdfghjqwertyuioplkmnbvcdfhjknbv',sqltcket)
    sqltcket = sqltcket +" where user_id='"+user_id+"' and business_unit='"+bu+"'"
```

I have tried to convert Django ORM:
validateexcel.py:

```
sqltcket = DboardComputedSystemUserSetting.objects.filter(user_id = user_id, business_unit = bu).values_list('ticket_limit', flat = True)
```

models.py:

```
class DboardComputedSystemUserSetting(models.Model):
    setting_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    email_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    bu_registration_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_admin = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    business_unit = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    buexpiry = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    ticket_limit = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'dboard_computed_system_user_setting'
        unique_together = (('setting_id', 'setting_id'))
```

error:
invalid literal or base10: exception in queryDB: argument 1 must be string or unicode object:queryset instead

Please anyone can help me with these.

Comment: It looks llike you use `sqltcket` as *query*, but you constructed a queryset, this means that if you *enumerate* over the `sqltcket` for example it will make the query and present the *results*, it does not produce a string to do the query.

Comment: what's does sqlticket look like?

Comment: Hi willem . I have taken sqltcket  is an variable.

Comment: Actually, In my project didn't use ORM's . so they write raw queries, i want to raw query into ORM.

Answer (score 0):

```
sqltcket = DboardComputedSystemUserSetting.objects.filter(user_id = user_id, business_unit = bu).values_list('ticket_limit', flat = True)
```

looks like your `user_id` variable is a queryset instead of an string

I am imagining that you used a filter to get `user_id` like

```
user_id = Users.objects.filter(id=random_variable)
```

this returns a queryset, which could have 0,1 or multiple users instead of a string.

if user_id is indeed a queryset as I am assuming.
And if you want to filter by a single user, and you are sure variable `user_id` has a single user, you could user the following

```
DboardComputedSystemUserSetting.objects.filter(user_id = user_id.first().id, ... )...
```

if for some reason you want fo filter by multiple users you could use

```
DboardComputedSystemUserSetting.objects.filter(user_id__in = user_id.values('id')... )...
```

You can run raw queries in Django, but i am not sure it's advisable https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries